# Visual Studio Test task runvstest error

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, azure-pipelines-build-task, vstest

The other day our UT started to fail (without any change) due this following error:

> Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file src\win\timer.c, line
>   37
>
> [error]Exit code 3 returned from process: file name 'C:\New
>   Agent\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\New
>   Agent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.0.55\runvstest.js"'.
>
> [debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessExitCodeException:
>   Exit code 3 returned from process: file name 'C:\New
>   Agent\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\New
>   Agent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.0.55\runvstest.js"'.

Any clue what could the problem be?

Comment: Are you able to get a successful build before? Do you use VSTS or on-premise TFS? Do you use hosted build agent or private build agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean folder `C:\New Agent\_work\_tasks`and have another test.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the content of that folder and it works properly. Do you know why?

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your VSTest task (`Exit code 3 returned from process: file name 'C:\New Agent\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\New Agent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.0.55\runvstest.js"'`), after you clear the folder, the tasks will be downloaded again during build.

Comment: Hi, the issue started to appear again. I've checked that if I restart the OS, it works properly. Could the machine be the problem?